# Call MATLAB function from a C program

Tags: c, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call MATLAB code from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513583/how-to-call-matlab-code-from-c)

Is there a method to call a MATLAB function from a C program?
My task is to calculate a pseudo inverse of a matrix generated in a C program using MATLAB. I want to pass the output obtained from MATLAB back to the C program again where it would undergo some calculations.

Comment: don't the makers of matlab offer software to compiler your matlab functions into objects callable from C?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f29148.html

Comment: If this is all that you're doing in Matlab, why not use [CLapack](http://www.netlib.org/clapack/) instead?  You'll save yourself quite a bit of overhead (linking all/most of Matlab), and be able to distribute your code to non-Matlab users.

Comment: this one also has a nice overview: [matlab in C C++ and C C++ in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1576876/97160)

Comment: Thanx all...actually my work wont be sticked to these basic operations...i've to write my user defined functions which are to be called from C compiler for calculations...Thanks a lot for ur support...