# Implement Matlab Interp2d in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, interpolation

Anyone know how to implement the function interp2d in matlab using c++?
Or can we link the matlab function into c++?

Comment: It would be useful if you described what this function is supposed to do.

Comment: see this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576876/matlab-in-c-c-and-c-c-in-matlab.  you may need to generate shared libraries from Matlab code such that you can use it in C/C+=.

Comment: Do you need all the different options that the Matlab function offers (in terms of types of interpolation - bicubic, linear etc)? Did you look at "Numerical Recipes in C" for algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV (http://www.opencv.org) is a heavy-weight dependency, but it's probably the tool you want if you're planning on doing image processing in c++.  `remap()` is the OpenCV function that provides the functionality of MATLAB `interp2d`.

Or, if you're happy with bilinear interpolation, and you don't care about performance, write it yourself.  The simple implementation is easy to write.  On the other hand, making it go faster is very hard, so if you care about performance, use OpenCV.